# Difference in comparing DateTime and parsed DateTimeOffset ticks

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, .net-core, datetimeoffset

I have two applications. A client app, and a server app.

The client app sends a HTTP request to the server where the request body contains a `DateTime`.

On the server I receive that `DateTime`, convert it to `Ticks` and save that in a SQLite database. (You could argue about why Ticks, but that's just the way this application is build..)

So far so good.

Not much later (a few minutes) the server application does a query to the database where it tries to query all the records of the past 30 minutes.

In code I do something like this to get the current `DateTime` minus the 30 minutes:

```
DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMinutes(-30).Ticks;
```

For some reason this number is bigger than the Timestamp of the newly created records.

I am probably missing something, but I just don't see it...

Here is a piece of code that perfectly mimicks my problem. (Link to working demo at bottom of post)

```
public static void Main()
{
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Client app
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    var clientTimestamp = DateTimeOffset.Now.DateTime;
    var jsonDateTime = clientTimestamp.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.fffZ");


    // Then, the client app sends data as JSON to the server app...


    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Server app
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    // Mimick as if we received a json string with a DateTime in it. Parse that back to a real DateTime object.
    // This is also the value that will be stored in the database
    var serverDateTime = DateTime.Parse(jsonDateTime);
    Console.WriteLine("Ticks serverDateTime:             " + serverDateTime.Ticks.ToString());


    // A minute or so later, a recurring job checks the database for newly added records in the range of: 30 minutes ago till now.

    // Create a new DateTime Now minus 30 minutes... Both Ticks values below are greater than the jsonDateTime ticks?

    // DateTimeOffset:
    // This value is larger, even with the minus -10 minutes?
    var nowDateTimeOffset = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMinutes(-10).Ticks.ToString();
    Console.WriteLine("Ticks nowDateTime -10 minutes:    " + nowDateTimeOffset);

    // DateTime
    // This value is larger, even with the minus -10 minutes?
    var nowDateTime = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMinutes(-10).Ticks.ToString();
    Console.WriteLine("Ticks nowDateTime -10 minutes:    " + nowDateTime);
}
```

Here is a demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/58Un0p

Comment: I'm guessing this is a typo but `jsonDateTime` is saved in `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.fffZ` not `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffz` (`hh` vs `HH`) which is causing a 12hr difference for me currently.  How big is the difference you see? The offset issue seems more likely though.

Comment: That ought to be the biggest problem.  Notable as well is that the DateTime.Ticks property value depends on the Kind property.  You have to make sure it is UTC to have any hope of getting comparable values.

Comment: @haldo That was actually causing the problem.... Could you please post that as an answer. Cause that fixes the issue for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, it seems the problem is the format of the DateTime:

```
"yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.fffZ"  // lower hh
```

whereas, it should be:

```
"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ"  // upper HH
```

Using 12 hour (`hh`) format rather than 24 hour (`HH`) format would cause a 12 hour difference 50% of the time!

---

As Hans mentions in the comments, you should ensure you're using UTC to compare the DateTime values. `DateTime.Parse` by default sets the DateTime kind to `DateTimeKind.Local`.  Is the client sending a UTC DateTime?

Update the client timestamp so it sends UTC DateTime with `ToUniversalTime`:

```
var clientTimestamp = DateTimeOffset.Now.ToUniversalTime();
```

Instead of `DateTime.Parse` consider `DateTime.ParseExact` with `AdjustToUniversal`:

```
// convert the date to UTC before saving to database
var utcServerDate = DateTime.ParseExact(jsonDateTime, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ", 
                         CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal);
```

And when comparing the `DateTimeOffset.Now` value use `UtcTicks`:

```
var nowDateTimeOffset = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMinutes(-30).UtcTicks;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, when trying to compare two DateTimeOffset, created with 0 (zero) milliseconds, and both with UTC.

In my research and long time debbuging this source code:

```
// local variable
DateTimeOffset datetime = DateTimeOffset.Parse ("2021-03-02T02:10:15.000Z");

// method
DateTimeOffset getNowTruncated () {
  DateTimeOffset now = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMilliseconds;
  now.AddMilliseconds (-now.Milliseconds);
}

// inside Main program
while (true) {
  if (getNowTruncated () == datetime) {
    break;
  } else {
    Console.WriteLine (getNowTruncated ());
  }
}
```

Both datetimes are the same year, month, day, hour, minutes, seconds, milleseconds, and unixtimestamp (using ToUnixTimeMilliseconds () method).

So, why the "break" is never triggered?

When I compare the TICKS of boths, I found the difference, so close to solve it ...

Searching about TICKS found the word NANOSECOND, so I guess that it's the problem, when creating datetime from DateTime.UtcNow it's creating with nanoseconds and it's is only visible when calling Ticks method, to avoid it, I created the next method:

```
public static DateTimeOffset GetNowTruncate ()
{
    DateTimeOffset now = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
    return new DateTimeOffset (now.Year, now.Month, now.Day,
        now.Hour, now.Minute, now.Second, TimeSpan.Zero);
}
```

When you can see, don't exist any parameter setting the nanoseconds, so it will be zero.